# There is no request token for this page in Twitter login case of Android

Tags: android, twitter

I integrated Twitter in my app. But I am facing a problem. I got a pin number like below.

[image]

And after this pin number, if I sign out, I get the below error:

> There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

How can I fix this problem?